# Return a Boolean value from one function to another function - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning VBA and I'm having trouble returning a boolean value from one function to another. I've been seeing other similar questions to try to solve but I couldn't.

So, I have this function :

```
Public Function Verifica_Permite_Gas()      
    Dim permit As Boolean       

' Se a torneira permite gasta
    If Permite_GAS Then         
        permit = True           
    Else

' Não permite
        Debug.Print "Erro torneira nao devia conter Gas - Torneira_3 - metodo Permite_GAS"          
        permit = False

    End If

End Function
```

And you should return the value for this function

```
Public Function Verifica_Gas()      
    Dim permite As Boolean

    permite = listaTorneiraSetor(a).Verifica_Permite_Gas()

End Function
```

The program works, has no errors but always returns false even when Permit_GAS = TRUE
I don't understand why, can someone help me solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in VBA are a bit funny in that they have no `return` statement like in some other languages. The way to return a value from a function is to assign the value to the function's name.

So inside `Verifica_Permite_Gas`, you just need to make sure at some point you have `Verifica_Permite_Gas = result`

you can imagine every `Function` containing a `Dim Verifica_Permite_Gas As ...` somewhere in there where you need to write the result.

So just get rid of `Dim permit As Boolean` and instead use:

```
Public Function Verifica_Permite_Gas()

' Se a torneira permite gasta
If Permite_GAS Then

    Verifica_Permite_Gas = True

Else
    ' Não permite
    Debug.Print "Erro torneira nao devia conter Gas - Torneira_3 - metodo Permite_GAS"

    Verifica_Permite_Gas = False

End If

End Function
```

---

Also remember that you declared `permit As Boolean` - well you can do the same with your function return value so it is

```
Public Function Verifica_Permite_Gas() As Boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your original function to return a value:

```
Public Function Verifica_Permite_Gas() As Boolean
    Dim permit As Boolean
' Se a torneira permite gasta
    If Permite_GAS Then
        permit = True
    Else
' Não permite
        Debug.Print "Erro torneira nao devia conter Gas - Torneira_3 - metodo Permite_GAS"
        permit = False
    End If
    Verifica_Permite_Gas=permit
End Function
```

And you could do without declaring and using `permit` by setting `Verifica_Permite_Gas` directly to be True or False within the `If/Else/End If` block:

```
If Permite_GAS Then
    Verifica_Permite_Gas= True
Else
    Verifica_Permite_Gas= False
End If
```

Regards,